# How can I render markdown to a golang template(html or tmpl) with blackfriday?

Tags: html, go, render, markdown, martini

I use the Martini framework,I have some markdown file and I want render it as HTML in tmpl/html template.

The markdown file like this:

```
title: A Test Demo
---
##ABC
> 123
```

And the template file like this:

```
<head>
  <title>{{name}}</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>{{abc}}</h2>
  <blockquote>
    <p>{{xyz}}</p>
  </blockquote>
</body>
```

I use the blackfriday parse the markdown and return `[]byte` type,next step I wanna render the markdown file to this template and make each block to the right place,so how can I do this right way? Or use any way to do this better?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to use the [Funcs](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Funcs) method to add a custom function to the template function map. See the *Functions* section of [the template package docs](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) for more info.

Given a template file `page.html`, some writer `w` (probably an `http.ResponseWriter`), and some struct `p` with a field `Body` containing data to be put into a template field, you can do something like:

Define a function:

```
func markDowner(args ...interface{}) template.HTML {
    s := blackfriday.MarkdownCommon([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("%s", args...)))
    return template.HTML(s)
}
```

Add it to the template function map:

```
tmpl := template.Must(template.New("page.html").Funcs(template.FuncMap{"markDown": markDowner}).ParseFiles("page.html"))
```

Execute the template:

```
err := tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "page.html", p)
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
}
```

Then, in your template file, you can put something like:

```
{{.Body | markDown}}
```

And it will pass the `Body` through your `markDowner` function.

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/thOmLPgo3z)